# While calling a post request through Retrofit getting 400 bad request error

Tags: android, retrofit2

Through Postman API is working but same API is not working with Retrofit
I am getting 400 Bad Request with Retrofit

End Point which returns true or false
**@POST("/emrmegax/api/allscript/saveappointment")
Call saveAppointment (@Header("x-auth-token") String header1, @Body String yy);**

```
    and this is my method from where i am calling this above API
    private void saveAppoint(String token, Saveappointment mSaveappointment){
    APIInterface service = APIClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
    JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
    paramObject.put("ehrAppointmentId", "");
    paramObject.put("ehrPatientId", mSaveappointment.getEhrPatientId());
    paramObject.put("appointmentType", mSaveappointment.getAppointmentType());
    paramObject.put("ehrProviderAbbrev", mSaveappointment.getEhrProviderAbbrev());
    paramObject.put("ehrProviderId", mSaveappointment.getEhrProviderId());
    paramObject.put("reason", mSaveappointment.getReason());
    paramObject.put("startDateTime", mSaveappointment.getStartDateTime());

    Call<Boolean> call = service.saveAppointment(token, paramObject.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //boolean value=response.body();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "" + response.code() + " " + response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
          Toast.makeText(mcontext, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A 400 Bad Request error means that the request the client made is incorrect or corrupt, and the server can't understand(parse) it.
Some causes of 400 Bad Request error:

- Invalid url.
- Invalid/Missing Header.

Maybe response error body contains some detailed message?

Comment: I tried many ways which didn't worked out .Then tried volley ,which is working smoothly. Thank you